# Attach function (not event) to dynamically created object

Tags: jquery

To attach a date picker to an input element, I'm using a date-picker plugin like so:

```
$('.foo').simpleDatePicker();
```

How would I attach this function to dynamically created $('.foo')s, so that if I append another $('.foo') element to the page, the simpleDatePicker function is already attached?

I would prefer to do it on document.ready instead of every time it is appended. Neither 'live()' nor 'bind()' seemed appropriate.

Comment: You can't attach another `$("#foo")` to the page, as element ids must be unique.

Comment: Simple answer, unfortunately, is that you can't. What you are asking for is that every time an element with a certain selector (say, "input.datepicker") is added to the document, simpleDatePicker() is automatically run on it. There's currently no ideal way to do this, except to call simpleDatePicker() manually every time you create one.

Comment: AFAIK you'd need to do it when it's appended (assuming it's a different ID, of course :) I'd probably try playing with firing an event with the ID as payload and binding to that event.

Comment: John - typo, now corrected. Elliot - thanks for the response, will have to stick to the current method.

Comment: [LiveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) might be worth looking at, however it doesn't mention being able to do "oncreate" sort of events.

Comment: Thanks JamWaffles, interesting plugin, was able to bind the date-picker to the element but not to subsequently appended elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .live for this using a late-binding technique.

```
$(".foo:not(.live)").live('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('live').datepicker().click();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I like that solution a lot - not only does it answer the initial question, you'll probably get performance benefits from lazy loading. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the jQuery `append` method and build a rule into the overloaded method that applies the `.simpleDatePicker()` to all `.foo` elements.

It's not really a solution i will recommend however, since the overhead of every `append` call seems a much greater cost to me than the gain. But if you are really looking for and need the convenience, then that is probably the only solution.